# Cause of SharpSVN Exceptions popping up what appears to be randomly when trying to Export?

Tags: c#, api, export, sharpsvn

I know something is going on, but I cannot determine why and the Exception strings are so vague... I have no clue why some things are failing and why some are not. These exceptions occur when I attempt to Export a file at a revision to the file system. Here are the exceptions:

> SharpSvn.SvnSystemException: Can't move 'C:....\tempfile.tmp' to 'C:...\temp.txt': Access is denied.
>   SharpSvn.SvnInvalidNodeKindException: 'C:....\temp.txt' exists and is not a directory

Now the oddest part about this whole thing is that the export works some of the time but not all of the time. I do not understand why I would have access one second and the next not have access. And the second exception... well it is the exact same line I call several times, sometimes it decides it wants to work others it doesn't. The string is supposed to be a file and it exists, so I don't see where the problem is. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Bah, as soon as I ask a question I discover a tiny mistake with large repercussion >.< 

How do you delete questions?

Comment: You can click delete on the question :)

Answer (score 1):

If you ended up at this question because of an SVN Exception saying it "can't open tempfile.tmp", then it may be because the directory to which you are trying to Export a file does not exist.  SharpSVN won't create missing subdirectories in your file's destination path.